# Loop throw list of strings to create row and columns

Tags: flutter, dart, for-loop

Hey guys i just started learning flutter recently and i ran into a problem i cant solve. Basically I have a list of numbers, results = (1,1,6,1,6,7,2,1), always even number of numbers in list, and i want to place them in a row that has columns of 2 numbers one below the other. I want two numbers in a row to always go in one column, one below the other. And the next 2 in the next column. And so on as long as I have numbers. And i want that list to look like on the photo i post.

I try

```
                Column(
                   children: [
                     for (var i = 0; result.length < i; i++)
                       Text(
                         result[i],
                       ),
                   ],
                 ),
```

[image: I want to look like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: result
                  .map(
                    (string) => Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4, left: 4),
                          child: 
                           Text(
                            string.split(':')[0],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 6,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          string.split(':')[1],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use Map
like this

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<String> names;
  //or int whatever list you want

  const MyWidget(
      {Key? key,
   
      required this.names})
      : super(key: key);
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Row(
    ///or Column
    children: names.map((e) => Text(e)).toList()
    //you can modify Text widget here also like adding styles or so
  );
}
```

Comment: Basically I have a list of numbers, results = (1,1,6,1,6,7,2,1), always even number of numbers in list, and i want to place them in a row that has columns of 2 numbers one below the other. I want two numbers in a row to always go in one column, one below the other. And the next 2 in the next column. And so on as long as I have numbers. And i want that list to look like on the photo i post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make two rows, one above the other, that contain numbers and these two rows have the same length because your list has an even number of members?

If so, you can do it exactly as the statement.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<int> result;

  const MyWidget(
      {Key? key,
   
      required this.names})
      : super(key: key);
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: list.getRange(0, range).map((e) => Text('$e')).toList(),
        ),
        Row(
          children: list.getRange(range, list.length).map((e) => Text('$e')).toList(),
        ),
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

So, you create a row with the first elements from 0 to the middle of your list, next you create a row from the middle to the end of your list.
In the function getRange(start, end) "start" is inclusive and "end" is exclusive.

Alternatively, there is a Widget called Wrap that do the work of dividing your rows or columns whenever there is no space available.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

I recommend you the Flutter´s Youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/c/flutterdev for learning more about Widgets and TheFlutterWay to learn about layout and apps creation https://www.youtube.com/c/TheFlutterWay

Comment: Actually I have a list of numbers. And I want two numbers to always go in one column, one below the other. And the next 2 in the next column. And so on as long as I have numbers. Like i have list results = (1,1,6,1,6,7,2,1) and i want that list to look like on the photo i post. Or maybe i can create two row and in one row to put every odd index in list, and in another even. What is better solution?

Comment: I saw your solution. It's great! Maybe a little too overkilled. I'd take my solution and your comment and do something like Row( children: list.filter(e -> e %2 ==0).map...

Answer (score 0):

[image: final rendr]

**I solved it using an extension method on Iterable, and a custom RowRenderer widget which makes use of that extension!**

See [this for code](https://github.com/flutterninja9/column_placer/blob/main/lib/src/sample_feature/sample_item_list_view.dart)